# What is the point of an Infallible Result, over just returning the Ok() branch?

Tags: rust, warp, rust-result

The [canonical example of a Warp rejection handler](https://github.com/seanmonstar/warp/blob/master/examples/rejections.rs#L80) is

```
async fn handle_rejection(err: Rejection) -> Result<impl Reply, Infallible> {
```

But what's the advantage of a `Result<ok, err>` such that the err is Infallible and can never be reached? Why not just return an `impl Reply`?

Comment: It's mostly useful for generic programming, e.g. where a trait can return an error using an associated type, but may not actually represent a fallible operation.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It usually means one of two things:

- The function is part of a trait, and the trait declaration indicates that the method can fail and return a `Result<T, E>`. Now, some implementations of that trait might happen not to have a fail path, and use an `Infallible`-like type for `E`.

  A standard library example of this is the `FromStr` trait. `FromStr` can obviously fail when implemented on `u32`, but not when implemented on `String`. Therefore `impl FromStr for String` uses `std::convert::Infallible` for its error case.
- The function is going to be used in a context that expects a fallible function.

  This is the case in your example. `handle_rejection` is passed to [`warp::Filter::recover`](https://docs.rs/warp/0.3.1/warp/trait.Filter.html#method.recover), which expects a fallible function. This makes sense as not all errors are recoverable, therefore `recover` might still have to deal with these.

  Now, this is a toy example that happens to be able to handle all errors, and therefore use `Infallible`.